# Restore duplicated folder to a specific date on Windows Home Server?

Tags: hp-mediasmart, windows-home-server

I am not very knowledgable with WHS in general.  Basically there is a file in a shared/duplicated user folder that has been modified but needs to be rolled back to a version from a couple days ago.
Is that possible with an HP MediaSmart Windows Home Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible with the backup feature. If your WHS is being backed up (similar to the Computer Client backup) then you would be able to roll back to a previous version.

Comment: Like if I had an external hdd connected that the server backed up to?  That's what you're saying right?

Comment: He means if the Home Server has a recent backup of that folder. It would show up under Previous Versions I believe.